# Two problems with the p3dx! Stalls and emergencies and the white "MOTORS" Button

Tags: ros, pioneer-3dx, p3dx, p2os-driver, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two questions or problems with my Pioneer 3 DX.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ROS Kinetic Kame and the p2os package,

After a successful connecting with the p2os_driver I have to push the white "MOTORS" button at the side of the P3DX. Is there a terminal command to release the brakes / the engine so I can start right away? Without pushing the white button?

My second question:
If I drive with the p3dx with a high construction it comes that the robot wiggles in curves and turns off. Is there a way to disable the ESTALL / STALL emergency? Change some parameters? I read, that is possible with the ARCOS see Pioneer 3 Operations Manual at STALLS AND EMERGENCIES.... But I do not understand how to do this with the p2os package...

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267740/two-problems-with-the-p3dx!-stalls-and-emergencies-and-the-white-%22motors%22-button-../) by [IcePick88](https://answers.ros.org/users/31393/icepick88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-07-31**:
You definitely found the right way to do the motors. You might look at the launch files -- there's several in the `p2os_launch` package that do most of the motor enable commands for you. As for the `ESTALL/STALL` emergency, I don't know off the top of my head, but, if you file an issue on the repo

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-07-31**:
I can get to it when I have a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you change the ARCOS configuration parameters and save them using the `ARCOScf` tool, then the parameters will be saved and used as defaults for all future connections.   Software such as `p2os` could override the parameter for its current connection session by sending certain commands, but I would guess that `p2os` probably doesn't do this for `STALLVAL`.

Make sure your added construction or equipment is balanced and is not too heavy.  See the robot manual for recommended payload weight limit for good control.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0